# How to get all messages between sender id and receiver id on mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im making a chat application with node js and mysql and i need to get all the data between sender id and receiver id but im stuck in that .

[Need to get all the communications between these 2 id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVrx7.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (sender = '" + request.body.sender + "' AND receiver = '" + request.body.receiver + "') OR (sender = '" + request.body.receiver + "' AND receiver = '" + request.body.sender + "')"
```

Comment: @JonasMetzler Documenting solutions on StackOverflow can still help other users who have the same problem. (At least if nobody else has already asked the same question, otherwise you should not create a duplicate.)